# The tail $\sigma$-field of Brownian motion

Tags: probability-theory, brownian-motion

I'm working on the proof of the following theorem given by Durrett's "[Probability](https://services.math.duke.edu/%7Ertd/PTE/PTE5_011119.pdf)."

> Theorem 7.2.7 If $A \in \mathcal{T}$, then either $P_x(A) \equiv 0$ or $P_x(A) \equiv 1$.

Here, $\mathcal{T} = \cap_{t\geq 0}\mathcal{F}_t'$, where $\mathcal{F}_t^\prime = \sigma(B_s: s \geq t)$. In words, $\mathcal{F}_t^\prime$ is the future at time $t$ and $\mathcal{T}$ is the tail $\sigma$-field of Brownian motion.

In the proof, Durrett says that for $A \in \mathcal{T}$ we can write $1_A = 1_D \circ \theta_1$ since $A \in \mathcal{F}_1^\prime$. Here, $D \in \mathcal{F}_0^+$, and when $\omega$ is a Brownian path, i.e. $B_t(\omega) = \omega(t)$, $\theta_s$, the shift transformation is defined as $(\theta_s \omega)(t)= \omega (s+t)$.

This is where I don't quite understand.

While I understand that, intuitively, $A \in \mathcal{F}_1^\prime$ means information about $t\geq 1$ is given. So, it is reasonable to think that $1_A = 1_D \circ \theta_1$ holds. But, how can we justify this conclusion rigorously?

Any help is very much appreciated!

---

I think I've come up with a solution to this problem. Here's the solution.

Let $\mathcal{P}$ be the collection of sets of form $A = \cap_{i=1}^n \{\omega(t_i) \in A_i\}$, where $1\geq t_1 < t_2 < \cdots < t_n$ and $A_i$ are Borel sets in $\mathbb{R}$. Then, $\mathcal{P}$ is a $\pi$-system.

For $A\in \mathcal{P}$,
$$
1_A(\omega) = \prod_{i=1}^n 1_{A_i}(\omega(t_i)) = \prod_{i=1}^n 1_{A_i}(\omega(t_i-1+1)) = \prod_{i=1}^n 1_{A_i}[(\theta_1\omega)(t_i-1)]
$$

By defining $D = \cap_{i=1}^n\{\omega(t_i-1)\in A_i\}$, we can write $1_A (\omega)= 1_D \circ \theta_1(\omega)$.

Now that the desired conclusion is verified for $A \in \mathcal{P}$, we can complete the proof by the $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem.

Is there any flaw in my reasoning?

Comment: what is the shift operator here? Anyway, probably you can use the fact that if $A\in \mathcal{T}$ it means that, there is some $s\geqslant 0$ such that $A\in \mathcal{F}'_t$ for all $t>s$

Comment: @Masacroso Added the definition of the shift transformation.

Answer (score 1):

In general, a $\mathbb R$-valued (or $\{0,1\}$-valued, in your case) random variable $Z$ which is measurable with regards to the $\sigma$-algebra $\sigma(Y)$ where $Y$ is a random variable, can be rewritten $Z = f\circ Y$ where $f$ is measurable from  the range of $Y$.

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Factorization_Lemma/Real-Valued_Function

That's a useful "abstract nonsense" lemma to have in your pocket.

In your case, $\mathcal{F}_1^\prime = \sigma(B_s: s \geq 1) = \sigma(\theta_1)$, by definition of $\theta_1$.

Comment: I know that fact. However, here we have the uncountable number of random variables $B_s, s \geq 1$.

Comment: An uncountable number of variables is a random variable in the product space, for the cylindrical sigma-algebra. Alternatively since your process is continuous it is a random variable in the wiener space of continuous functions, with its Borel sigma algebra. It turns out that those sigma algebras are actually the same. Anyway you are allowed to view a random process as a single random variable.

Comment: That's new to me. Any reference?

Comment: These notes by Ron Peled are quite good. http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~peledron/Teaching/Brownian_motion/Sigma_algebra_notes.pdf

Comment: Apparently, according to this question the subject is also treated in  Karatzas&Shreve https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3376232/the-sigma-algebra-mathscrb-leftc-left0-infty-right-right-is-genera